How to create a React Native Paper theme with Material Theme Builder using a JSON
I created a custom theme using Material Theme Builder which I exported as a JSON file.
I was wondering what is the best way of converting this file to a useable React Native Paper theme?
The JSON file for reference:
{
    "description": "",
    "seed": "#2196F3",
    "coreColors": {
        "primary": "#2196F3",
        "secondary": "#8E33FF",
        "tertiary": "#000000",
        "error": "#FF5630",
        "neutral": "#909094",
        "neutralVariant": "#7C7C7C"
    },
    "extendedColors": [],
    "schemes": {
        "light": {
            "primary": "#36618E",
            "surfaceTint": "#36618E",
            "onPrimary": "#FFFFFF",
            "primaryContainer": "#D1E4FF",
            "onPrimaryContainer": "#001D36",
            "secondary": "#6B538C",
            "onSecondary": "#FFFFFF",
            "secondaryContainer": "#EDDCFF",
            "onSecondaryContainer": "#250E44",
            "tertiary": "#8C4A60",
            "onTertiary": "#FFFFFF",
            "tertiaryContainer": "#FFD9E2",
            "onTertiaryContainer": "#3A071D",
            "error": "#904B3B",
            "onError": "#FFFFFF",
            "errorContainer": "#FFDAD2",
            "onErrorContainer": "#3A0A02",
            "background": "#F8F9FF",
            "onBackground": "#191C20",
            "surface": "#F9F9FF",
            "onSurface": "#191C20",
            "surfaceVariant": "#DBE4E6",
            "onSurfaceVariant": "#3F484A",
            "outline": "#6F797A",
            "outlineVariant": "#BFC8CA",
            "shadow": "#000000",
            "scrim": "#000000",
            "inverseSurface": "#2E3035",
            "inverseOnSurface": "#F0F0F7",
            "inversePrimary": "#A0CAFD",
            "primaryFixed": "#D1E4FF",
            "onPrimaryFixed": "#001D36",
            "primaryFixedDim": "#A0CAFD",
            "onPrimaryFixedVariant": "#194975",
            "secondaryFixed": "#EDDCFF",
            "onSecondaryFixed": "#250E44",
            "secondaryFixedDim": "#D6BBFB",
            "onSecondaryFixedVariant": "#523C73",
            "tertiaryFixed": "#FFD9E2",
            "onTertiaryFixed": "#3A071D",
            "tertiaryFixedDim": "#FFB1C8",
            "onTertiaryFixedVariant": "#703348",
            "surfaceDim": "#D9D9E0",
            "surfaceBright": "#F9F9FF",
            "surfaceContainerLowest": "#FFFFFF",
            "surfaceContainerLow": "#F3F3FA",
            "surfaceContainer": "#EDEDF4",
            "surfaceContainerHigh": "#E7E8EE",
            "surfaceContainerHighest": "#E2E2E9"
        },
        "light-medium-contrast": {
            "primary": "#134570",
            "surfaceTint": "#36618E",
            "onPrimary": "#FFFFFF",
            "primaryContainer": "#4D77A6",
            "onPrimaryContainer": "#FFFFFF",
            "secondary": "#4E386F",
            "onSecondary": "#FFFFFF",
            "secondaryContainer": "#816AA4",
            "onSecondaryContainer": "#FFFFFF",
            "tertiary": "#6B2F44",
            "onTertiary": "#FFFFFF",
            "tertiaryContainer": "#A55F76",
            "onTertiaryContainer": "#FFFFFF",
            "error": "#6E3122",
            "onError": "#FFFFFF",
            "errorContainer": "#AA604F",
            "onErrorContainer": "#FFFFFF",
            "background": "#F8F9FF",
            "onBackground": "#191C20",
            "surface": "#F9F9FF",
            "onSurface": "#191C20",
            "surfaceVariant": "#DBE4E6",
            "onSurfaceVariant": "#3B4446",
            "outline": "#576162",
            "outlineVariant": "#737C7E",
            "shadow": "#000000",
            "scrim": "#000000",
            "inverseSurface": "#2E3035",
            "inverseOnSurface": "#F0F0F7",
            "inversePrimary": "#A0CAFD",
            "primaryFixed": "#4D77A6",
            "onPrimaryFixed": "#FFFFFF",
            "primaryFixedDim": "#335E8B",
            "onPrimaryFixedVariant": "#FFFFFF",
            "secondaryFixed": "#816AA4",
            "onSecondaryFixed": "#FFFFFF",
            "secondaryFixedDim": "#68518A",
            "onSecondaryFixedVariant": "#FFFFFF",
            "tertiaryFixed": "#A55F76",
            "onTertiaryFixed": "#FFFFFF",
            "tertiaryFixedDim": "#89475E",
            "onTertiaryFixedVariant": "#FFFFFF",
            "surfaceDim": "#D9D9E0",
            "surfaceBright": "#F9F9FF",
            "surfaceContainerLowest": "#FFFFFF",
            "surfaceContainerLow": "#F3F3FA",
            "surfaceContainer": "#EDEDF4",
            "surfaceContainerHigh": "#E7E8EE",
            "surfaceContainerHighest": "#E2E2E9"
        },
        "light-high-contrast": {
            "primary": "#002341",
            "surfaceTint": "#36618E",
            "onPrimary": "#FFFFFF",
            "primaryContainer": "#134570",
            "onPrimaryContainer": "#FFFFFF",
            "secondary": "#2C164B",
            "onSecondary": "#FFFFFF",
            "secondaryContainer": "#4E386F",
            "onSecondaryContainer": "#FFFFFF",
            "tertiary": "#420E24",
            "onTertiary": "#FFFFFF",
            "tertiaryContainer": "#6B2F44",
            "onTertiaryContainer": "#FFFFFF",
            "error": "#431106",
            "onError": "#FFFFFF",
            "errorContainer": "#6E3122",
            "onErrorContainer": "#FFFFFF",
            "background": "#F8F9FF",
            "onBackground": "#191C20",
            "surface": "#F9F9FF",
            "onSurface": "#000000",
            "surfaceVariant": "#DBE4E6",
            "onSurfaceVariant": "#1C2527",
            "outline": "#3B4446",
            "outlineVariant": "#3B4446",
            "shadow": "#000000",
            "scrim": "#000000",
            "inverseSurface": "#2E3035",
            "inverseOnSurface": "#FFFFFF",
            "inversePrimary": "#E2EDFF",
            "primaryFixed": "#134570",
            "onPrimaryFixed": "#FFFFFF",
            "primaryFixedDim": "#002E52",
            "onPrimaryFixedVariant": "#FFFFFF",
            "secondaryFixed": "#4E386F",
            "onSecondaryFixed": "#FFFFFF",
            "secondaryFixedDim": "#372157",
            "onSecondaryFixedVariant": "#FFFFFF",
            "tertiaryFixed": "#6B2F44",
            "onTertiaryFixed": "#FFFFFF",
            "tertiaryFixedDim": "#50192E",
            "onTertiaryFixedVariant": "#FFFFFF",
            "surfaceDim": "#D9D9E0",
            "surfaceBright": "#F9F9FF",
            "surfaceContainerLowest": "#FFFFFF",
            "surfaceContainerLow": "#F3F3FA",
            "surfaceContainer": "#EDEDF4",
            "surfaceContainerHigh": "#E7E8EE",
            "surfaceContainerHighest": "#E2E2E9"
        },
        "dark": {
            "primary": "#A0CAFD",
            "surfaceTint": "#A0CAFD",
            "onPrimary": "#003258",
            "primaryContainer": "#194975",
            "onPrimaryContainer": "#D1E4FF",
            "secondary": "#D6BBFB",
            "onSecondary": "#3B255B",
            "secondaryContainer": "#523C73",
            "onSecondaryContainer": "#EDDCFF",
            "tertiary": "#FFB1C8",
            "onTertiary": "#541D32",
            "tertiaryContainer": "#703348",
            "onTertiaryContainer": "#FFD9E2",
            "error": "#FFB4A3",
            "onError": "#561F12",
            "errorContainer": "#733426",
            "onErrorContainer": "#FFDAD2",
            "background": "#111418",
            "onBackground": "#E1E2E8",
            "surface": "#111318",
            "onSurface": "#E2E2E9",
            "surfaceVariant": "#3F484A",
            "onSurfaceVariant": "#BFC8CA",
            "outline": "#899294",
            "outlineVariant": "#3F484A",
            "shadow": "#000000",
            "scrim": "#000000",
            "inverseSurface": "#E2E2E9",
            "inverseOnSurface": "#2E3035",
            "inversePrimary": "#36618E",
            "primaryFixed": "#D1E4FF",
            "onPrimaryFixed": "#001D36",
            "primaryFixedDim": "#A0CAFD",
            "onPrimaryFixedVariant": "#194975",
            "secondaryFixed": "#EDDCFF",
            "onSecondaryFixed": "#250E44",
            "secondaryFixedDim": "#D6BBFB",
            "onSecondaryFixedVariant": "#523C73",
            "tertiaryFixed": "#FFD9E2",
            "onTertiaryFixed": "#3A071D",
            "tertiaryFixedDim": "#FFB1C8",
            "onTertiaryFixedVariant": "#703348",
            "surfaceDim": "#111318",
            "surfaceBright": "#37393E",
            "surfaceContainerLowest": "#0C0E13",
            "surfaceContainerLow": "#191C20",
            "surfaceContainer": "#1D2024",
            "surfaceContainerHigh": "#282A2F",
            "surfaceContainerHighest": "#33353A"
        },
        "dark-medium-contrast": {
            "primary": "#A6CEFF",
            "surfaceTint": "#A0CAFD",
            "onPrimary": "#00172D",
            "primaryContainer": "#6A94C4",
            "onPrimaryContainer": "#000000",
            "secondary": "#DABFFF",
            "onSecondary": "#20073F",
            "secondaryContainer": "#9F85C2",
            "onSecondaryContainer": "#000000",
            "tertiary": "#FFB7CC",
            "onTertiary": "#330218",
            "tertiaryContainer": "#C67B92",
            "onTertiaryContainer": "#000000",
            "error": "#FFBAAB",
            "onError": "#330500",
            "errorContainer": "#CB7C69",
            "onErrorContainer": "#000000",
            "background": "#111418",
            "onBackground": "#E1E2E8",
            "surface": "#111318",
            "onSurface": "#FBFAFF",
            "surfaceVariant": "#3F484A",
            "onSurfaceVariant": "#C3CCCE",
            "outline": "#9BA5A6",
            "outlineVariant": "#7B8587",
            "shadow": "#000000",
            "scrim": "#000000",
            "inverseSurface": "#E2E2E9",
            "inverseOnSurface": "#282A2F",
            "inversePrimary": "#1B4A76",
            "primaryFixed": "#D1E4FF",
            "onPrimaryFixed": "#001225",
            "primaryFixedDim": "#A0CAFD",
            "onPrimaryFixedVariant": "#003862",
            "secondaryFixed": "#EDDCFF",
            "onSecondaryFixed": "#1A023A",
            "secondaryFixedDim": "#D6BBFB",
            "onSecondaryFixedVariant": "#412B61",
            "tertiaryFixed": "#FFD9E2",
            "onTertiaryFixed": "#2B0012",
            "tertiaryFixedDim": "#FFB1C8",
            "onTertiaryFixedVariant": "#5B2238",
            "surfaceDim": "#111318",
            "surfaceBright": "#37393E",
            "surfaceContainerLowest": "#0C0E13",
            "surfaceContainerLow": "#191C20",
            "surfaceContainer": "#1D2024",
            "surfaceContainerHigh": "#282A2F",
            "surfaceContainerHighest": "#33353A"
        },
        "dark-high-contrast": {
            "primary": "#FAFAFF",
            "surfaceTint": "#A0CAFD",
            "onPrimary": "#000000",
            "primaryContainer": "#A6CEFF",
            "onPrimaryContainer": "#000000",
            "secondary": "#FFF9FD",
            "onSecondary": "#000000",
            "secondaryContainer": "#DABFFF",
            "onSecondaryContainer": "#000000",
            "tertiary": "#FFF9F9",
            "onTertiary": "#000000",
            "tertiaryContainer": "#FFB7CC",
            "onTertiaryContainer": "#000000",
            "error": "#FFF9F8",
            "onError": "#000000",
            "errorContainer": "#FFBAAB",
            "onErrorContainer": "#000000",
            "background": "#111418",
            "onBackground": "#E1E2E8",
            "surface": "#111318",
            "onSurface": "#FFFFFF",
            "surfaceVariant": "#3F484A",
            "onSurfaceVariant": "#F3FCFE",
            "outline": "#C3CCCE",
            "outlineVariant": "#C3CCCE",
            "shadow": "#000000",
            "scrim": "#000000",
            "inverseSurface": "#E2E2E9",
            "inverseOnSurface": "#000000",
            "inversePrimary": "#002B4E",
            "primaryFixed": "#D9E8FF",
            "onPrimaryFixed": "#000000",
            "primaryFixedDim": "#A6CEFF",
            "onPrimaryFixedVariant": "#00172D",
            "secondaryFixed": "#F0E1FF",
            "onSecondaryFixed": "#000000",
            "secondaryFixedDim": "#DABFFF",
            "onSecondaryFixedVariant": "#20073F",
            "tertiaryFixed": "#FFDFE6",
            "onTertiaryFixed": "#000000",
            "tertiaryFixedDim": "#FFB7CC",
            "onTertiaryFixedVariant": "#330218",
            "surfaceDim": "#111318",
            "surfaceBright": "#37393E",
            "surfaceContainerLowest": "#0C0E13",
            "surfaceContainerLow": "#191C20",
            "surfaceContainer": "#1D2024",
            "surfaceContainerHigh": "#282A2F",
            "surfaceContainerHighest": "#33353A"
        }
    },
    "palettes": {
        "primary": {
            "0": "#000000",
            "5": "#001225",
            "10": "#001D36",
            "15": "#002747",
            "20": "#003258",
            "25": "#003D6A",
            "30": "#00497D",
            "35": "#005590",
            "40": "#0061A4",
            "50": "#007BCC",
            "60": "#1E95F2",
            "70": "#63B0FF",
            "80": "#9ECAFF",
            "90": "#D1E4FF",
            "95": "#EAF1FF",
            "98": "#F8F9FF",
            "99": "#FDFCFF",
            "100": "#FFFFFF"
        },
        "secondary": {
            "0": "#000000",
            "5": "#1A003C",
            "10": "#280056",
            "15": "#36006E",
            "20": "#440088",
            "25": "#5200A2",
            "30": "#6100BE",
            "35": "#7000DA",
            "40": "#7E15EF",
            "50": "#9648FF",
            "60": "#AC73FF",
            "70": "#C197FF",
            "80": "#D7BAFF",
            "90": "#EDDCFF",
            "95": "#F8EDFF",
            "98": "#FEF7FF",
            "99": "#FFFBFF",
            "100": "#FFFFFF"
        },
        "tertiary": {
            "0": "#000000",
            "5": "#111111",
            "10": "#1B1B1B",
            "15": "#262626",
            "20": "#303030",
            "25": "#3B3B3B",
            "30": "#474747",
            "35": "#525252",
            "40": "#5E5E5E",
            "50": "#777777",
            "60": "#919191",
            "70": "#ABABAB",
            "80": "#C6C6C6",
            "90": "#E2E2E2",
            "95": "#F1F1F1",
            "98": "#F9F9F9",
            "99": "#FCFCFC",
            "100": "#FFFFFF"
        },
        "neutral": {
            "0": "#000000",
            "5": "#111111",
            "10": "#1C1B1B",
            "15": "#262626",
            "20": "#313030",
            "25": "#3C3B3B",
            "30": "#484646",
            "35": "#535252",
            "40": "#605E5E",
            "50": "#797676",
            "60": "#929090",
            "70": "#ADAAAA",
            "80": "#C9C6C5",
            "90": "#E5E2E1",
            "95": "#F4F0EF",
            "98": "#FCF8F8",
            "99": "#FDFBFF",
            "100": "#FFFFFF"
        },
        "neutral-variant": {
            "0": "#000000",
            "5": "#111111",
            "10": "#1C1B1B",
            "15": "#262625",
            "20": "#313030",
            "25": "#3C3B3B",
            "30": "#484646",
            "35": "#535252",
            "40": "#5F5E5E",
            "50": "#787776",
            "60": "#929090",
            "70": "#ADABAA",
            "80": "#C9C6C5",
            "90": "#E5E2E1",
            "95": "#F4F0EF",
            "98": "#FCF8F8",
            "99": "#F6FEFF",
            "100": "#FFFFFF"
        }
    }
}

